# SQL Server trigger before insert

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2012

I have table with a few columns and I want to create a trigger that take the values from one or more columns and set the value in another column.

For example:

table test with columns test1, test2, test3.

I want to take the value from test2 and test3 and set them in test1.
The reason for that is test1 define as not null and the value must be test2+test3

Can i do this in trigger before insert?

Comment: SQL Server doesn't have `BEFORE INSERT` triggers - the only option (if you really must use a trigger) would be an `INSTEAD OF INSERT` trigger

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add a computed column like below,no need of trigger

```
create table t1
(
t1 as t2+t3,
t2 int,
t3 int
)
```

Comment: if the t1 is a not null, then would the above query work? I think t1 value should be retained if its not null and have to be computed from t2 and t3 if its null

Comment: I forgot to say that t2 and t3 are not null

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
IF OBJECT_ID('[dbo].[Demo]') IS NOT NULL
BEGIN
    DROP TABLE [dbo].[Demo];
END;

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Demo]
(
    [test1] INT NOT NULL
   ,[test2] INT
   ,[test3] INT
);

GO

/*
Msg 515, Level 16, State 2, Line 15
Cannot insert the value NULL into column 'test1', table 'TEST.dbo.Demo'; column does not allow nulls. INSERT fails.
*/

INSERT INTO [dbo].[Demo] ([test2], [test3])
VALUES (1, 1);

GO

CREATE TRIGGER TRG_DEMO_I_I ON [dbo].[Demo] INSTEAD  OF INSERT AS
BEGIN 

    INSERT INTO [dbo].[Demo] ([test1], [test2], [test3])
    SELECT [test2] + [test3], [test2], [test3]
    FROM inserted;
END;

GO

-- this is OK
INSERT INTO [dbo].[Demo] ([test2], [test3])
VALUES (1, 1);

SELECT *
FROM [dbo].[Demo];

GO
```